# Appengine frontend instances have been using more and more RAM, how can I reduce this?

Tags: google-app-engine

My instances all now start at 140m and average just under 200. If left long enough they start hitting 240m. However my question is more about the memory being used right after a fresh instance is booted up. I store nothing on the instances. Every request fetches stuff from memcache and datastore and I don't use singletons.

All I have are classes and a lot of static resources that deploy with the instances. I use JSPs extensively (if that makes a difference).

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I figured out why my project was taking up an ever increasing amount of ram. I happen to have a lot of static resources in my project and it would appear that these static resources all get loaded into the frontend instance memory (probably for speed). I managed to free up huge amounts of memory by moving my static resources off of my primary application servers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going from memory here, since I have used Java on App Engine for a few years. This may be stale.

The JVM doesn't like to release memory. If an instance gets created, and services a request, the memory watermark goes up. Garbage collection may  'free' part of that memory up in the sense of it being available for reuse, but the high watermark on process memory doesn't necessarily go down. A subsequent request may need allocations that aren't available as free chunks, so the watermark on memory goes up again. If the app isn't configured to serve multiple request simultaneously, memory use follows something like a sigmoid curve. If multiple requests are being processed simultaneously, the watermark is raised further.

That said, a common cause of unexpected memory growth is queries that retrieve more rows than are necessary, with filtering happening in the app.

But without more information, your specific case is impossible to diagnose.